# ng-grid changing first character in String into Uppercase in cellTemplate

Tags: ng-grid

I have a ng.grid in my application and I should capitalize the word in ng-grid's cell, so that first character would in uppercase. How should I do it?

I tried to use cellTemplate property in that field in ng-grid like following:

```
field : 'myField',
displayName : '',
cellTemplate : '{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}'
}, {
```

When testing 'text-transform':capitalize in ordinary HTML page it works. But in cellTemplate not at least code like above.

Have anyone ideas how define it into ng-grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own 'capitalizeFirst' filter:

```js
app.filter('uppercaseFirst', function () {
  return function (str) {
    return str.replace(/^(\w)/, function (w) { return w.toUpperCase(); });
  };
});
```

And then use it as a `cellFilter` on your column:

```js
{
  field : 'myField',
  cellFilter: 'uppercaseFirst'
}
```

Check this plunker for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/fllRIY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'cellTemplate' to change first letter case. Instead of writing separate function change cellTemplate like:

```
{
 cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity[col.field].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+
                 row.entity[col.field].substring(1)}}</div>' 
}
```

Thanks,